# Using a custom dictionary for spellcheck with an http url

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a WPF control that contains a TextBox that I would like to enable SpellCheck on, as well as use a custom dictionary.

```
<TextBox Name="SpellBoxControl" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" >
    <SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
        <system:Uri>\\network-share\customWords.lex</system:Uri>
    </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
</TextBox>
```

I've managed to get this to work just fine by using a custom dictionary that is located on a network share (as seen above), however I'd like to use a custom dictionary by providing the HTTP URL to it. When I try  to do that 
      `<system:Uri>http://network-share/customWords.lex</system:Uri>`, I get the exception: `"Only local file path or pack Uri is supported."`

I thought you could create a URI from an HTTP URL, but maybe this is not the case with custom dictionaries and SpellCheck. Is there anyway that I can access/use a custom dictionary over the internet for spell checking? Or am I sorely misunderstanding the use of URIs?

Comment: Do you get that error at compile time or at run time? If it's run time, then it's likely the problem is that the `SpellCheck` control is restricting the URI to be a local file path. To my knowledge, WPF in general doesn't have such a restriction.

Comment: What would you do if there is no network connection or the connection is dropped? It may be smarter to download this dictionary, save it locally and  periodically check (in the background, or in a separate process started at app shutdown) if the source dictionary has changed, so you can update the local version.

Comment: @JimMischel I get the error at run time. It might very well be a restriction by `SpellCheck`, though I couldn't find anything about it in the msdn documentation

Comment: In the Remarks section of the page describing the [CustomDictionaries property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx), it says: *The lexicon files can be included in the application as content files installed on the local computer or as resource files compiled into a local referenced assembly.*

Comment: @JimMischel Well I had read that line... but for whatever reason i didn't read it as those being the only two options. So I guess that would be the answer unless someone has a round-about way of accomplishing this..

Comment: @JimMischel If you'd like to post your previous comment as an answer I'll accept it. I don't believe I'm going to find any other solutions, and that sentence technically does answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpellCheck` control requires that the URI be to a local path. In the Remarks section of the page describing the [CustomDictionaries property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> The lexicon files can be included in the application as content files installed on the local computer or as resource files compiled into a local referenced assembly.